How to map different serverless logins (Facebook, Apple, Google Play) to one account in Unity CloudSave?
How can I map serverless different logins (Facebook, Apple, Google Play) to one Account in Unity CloudSave?
Or is it automatically done when we are logging in via AuthenticationService?
I read the documentation on approaches to authentication, but am still unclear on this use case.

Okay at the moment I can link Facebook account to one anonymous account but when I login to facebook on another account the data from previous account are not loaded.

I do not link the Facebook account, and it is loading data correctly if a user login on different devices to the same facebook account.
